# Displaying MySQL data in a ReactNative application

Tags: mysql, react-native, text

I want to display the data from my MySQL database, in my React Native application.

I am able to display the data in an alert message. But not in the application (for example, in a  tag).

How to do it?

The screenshot represents the display of data in an alert message :
[alert message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUoGw.png)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Text component and access the object's comment_test property from it.

Without further code, I can only provide an example:

```
<View>
<Text>{mysqlResponseObject.comment_test}</Text>
<View>
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your answer.
To be clearer, here is the code in question:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IKbziatMYDEkuFng8wsEf2Q1zlKAw6a8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: then, you should return responseJson from your function like so `return responseJson` and then from the component where you want to display the data (like in a text component) you will save it as a variable and access it like `nameOfTheVariable[0].comment_test` if you want the first object (Contre attaque) or `nameOfTheVariable[1].comment_test` for the other one

Comment: I tried to follow your advice, but I don't know if I did it right. I added this to my builder: https://urlz.fr/fu1X
Then I added this to my function (see breakpoints for what I added):https://urlz.fr/fu20
Then, I try to make the display in the application, like this: https://urlz.fr/fu22

But I still have this error: https://urlz.fr/fu25

What to do?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in a state then iterate through it. Use can update your state with setData function where you read the data from the database.

```jsx
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    
    function Example() {
      const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    
      return (
        <View>
          {data.map((item) => (
            <Text>{item.comment_test}</Text>
          ))}
        </View>
      );
    }
```